# Itinerary Combinatorics questions

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you are given a set of 10 cities (including Boston, New York, and Chicago), and
asked to plan an itinerary that visits each of the cities exactly once.

How many distinct itineraries have the property that you visit Boston before
New York (though not necessarily immediately before), and visit New York before
Chicago (though not necessarily immediately before)?

---

I started this question using compliments, starting with 10! total itineraries, and then subtracting the itineraries where Chicago is visited before New York, and where NY is visited before Boston.

My question is when it comes to calculating the number of those itineraries. Intuition tells me that it should be 9! for each case, but I'm not sure how to actually show this.

If that's correct, the answer to the question would be 10! - 2*9! = 2903040.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $3! = 6$ possible orders in which Boston, Chicago, and New York could be visited.  Of these, only one involves visiting Boston before New York and New York before Chicago.  Thus, by symmetry, in $1/6$th of the $10!$ possible itineraries is Boston visited before New York and New York visited before Chicago.  Hence, the number of such itineraries is 
$$\frac{1}{6} \cdot 10!$$

**Edit:**  In response to the question posed in the comments, you counted the number of excluded itineraries incorrectly.

If you wish to exclude those itineraries in which New York is visited before Boston or Chicago is visited before New York, we start with the $10!$ possible itineraries.  By symmetry, in half of the possible itineraries New York is visited before Boston.  Similarly, in half of the possible itineraries Chicago is visited before New York.  In subtracting these itineraries from the total possible number of itineraries, we have subtracted those in which New York is visited before Boston and Chicago is visited before New York twice.  Thus, we must add those itineraries to the total.  By the argument given above, in $1/6$th of the possible itineraries, New York is visited before Boston and Chicago is visited before New York.  Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the number of possible itineraries is 
$$10! - \frac{10!}{2} - \frac{10!}{2} + \frac{10!}{6} = \frac{10!}{6}$$

Alternatively, note that if we wish to count the number of itineraries in which New York is visited before Boston, we can choose two of the ten positions for New York and Boston, place New York in the leftmost of the selected positions and Boston in the other, then arrange the remaining eight cities in $8!$ orders.  Thus, the number of itineraries in which Boston is visited before New York is 
$$\binom{10}{2} \cdot 8! = \frac{10!}{2!8!} \cdot 8! = \frac{10!}{2!} = \frac{10!}{2}$$
and similarly for the number of itineraries in which Chicago is visited before New York.  However, as above, we have to take into account the possibility that Chicago is visited before New York and New York is visited before Boston.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So what is the fault in my logic, then?